# Delete all images older than 1 hour

Tags: php

I would like to delete all images from a folder called *tempimages* that are older than 1 hour.
I found the example below on Stack Overflow but I'm getting a parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '{' in /delete-old-images.php on line 13

```
<?php  
function destroy($dir) {
$mydir = opendir($dir);
while($file = readdir($mydir)) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
        if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
            chdir('.');
            while($dir.$file) {
                if(date("U",filectime($file) >= time() - 3600)
                {
                    unlink($dir.$file)
                }
            }

        }
        else
            unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
    }
}
closedir($mydir);
}

destroy("tempimages/");
?>
```

My server data:

```
PHP Version 5.3.18-nmm1
System  Linux #116-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 19:37:57 UTC 2013 x86_64 
Build Date  Oct 26 2012 16:30:11 
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `date()`

```
 if(date("U",filectime($file)) >= time() - 3600)
                      -------^
```

and missed a semi colon here

```
unlink($dir.$file);
             -----^
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't close the bracket for if condition.

```
if(date("U",filectime($file) >= time() - 3600)
```

Should be

```
if(date("U",filectime($file) >= time() - 3600))
```

and missed the semicolumn

```
unlink($dir.$file)
```

Should be

```
unlink($dir.$file);
```