# Files not getting deleted by date

Tags: php

I am trying to delete some file by date. If the file had been last modified yestarday needs to get deleted. I have the following script:

```
$docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$docroot = $docroot.'/scrapers/thumbnails/';
$i = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($docroot)) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
    $filelastmodified = filemtime($file);
    if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 6*3600)
    {
    $i++;
       unlink($file);
    echo $i.'files deleted<br>';
    }

  }
  closedir($handle); 
}
```

I checked other question on stackoverflow, but answers were a bit different. Please let me know where am I mistaking. Currently for testing purposes I added to delete the files that are older than 6 hours.

Comment: What is not working here as expected?

Comment: @GhostGambler Sorry, I pasted a testing version, unlink is not commented. First thing that is not working, is the delete process, second, from what is echoing on the testing page, all files are deleted, but there are only a few of them that matches the timing criteria that I selected in the if. So only the few that matches the criteria should be echoed.

Comment: Files should be deleted, if they were modified in the last 24 hours?

Comment: @GhostGambler the script should delete the files that are older than 6 hours.

Comment: Please put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to the top of your file.

Comment: I get following: `Warning: unlink(.): Is a directory in` line 10, `filemtime(): stat failed for 1395645475911521.png` and               `unlink(1395645475911521.png): No such file or directory`

Comment: found the script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204992/delete-all-images-older-than-1-hour, request and admin to close the question or delete it, as you want. Sorry for this. Should have searched deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php

    $docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $docroot = $docroot.'/scrapers/thumbnails/';
    if ($handle = opendir($docroot)) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
            $filelastmodified = filemtime($file);

            if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 6*3600)
            {
               unlink($file);
            }

        }

        closedir($handle); 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Actually, what are you expecting? In this code detect the last modified time (more than 6 hr) and delete the files.

Comment: Yes this is what I am expecting to delete files older than 6 hours. But it's not deleting them.

Comment: The place where you are running? I mean local host or your hosting server? I don't what is the error. This is running on my local host. But thing is if you are running the script on your hosting server I thing you have to give the permission to access the directory(777)

Comment: Same errors that I specified in the comment section of the question.

Comment: And yes I have permission 777 to directory + files.

Comment: @user3467855 your application is running on your local host or hosting server?

Comment: On Hosting server, sorry, did not read that part. Which is Debian.

Comment: Maybe my answer is wrong and chilly thing. :) If you can please check your directory. var_dump($docroot.'/scrapers/thumbnails/');

Comment: Did a vardump on that and it's echoing properly usr/username/... Just found the script and it's working properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204992/delete-all-images-older-than-1-hour

Comment: What is the error? If it is correct don't forget to accept the answer :D